# How to implement custom loss function with Keras?

Tags: deep-learning, keras

There is a paper [Beyond MSE](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.05440)

In this paper, the author proposed a gradient difference loss function.
[gradient difference loss function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tL6W.jpg), combined with MSE, the predicting result will be less blurry.

I am new to Keras, could you show me a direction how to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in https://github.com/jonasrothfuss/DeepEpisodicMemory/blob/master/models/loss_functions.py

```
def gradient_difference_loss(true, pred, alpha=2.0):
  """
  computes gradient difference loss of two images
  :param ground truth image: Tensor of shape (batch_size, frame_height, frame_width, num_channels)
  :param predicted image: Tensor of shape (batch_size, frame_height, frame_width, num_channels)
  :param alpha parameter of the used l-norm
  """
  #tf.assert_equal(tf.shape(true), tf.shape(pred))
  # vertical
  true_pred_diff_vert = tf.pow(tf.abs(difference_gradient(true, vertical=True) - difference_gradient(pred, vertical=True)), alpha)
  # horizontal
  true_pred_diff_hor = tf.pow(tf.abs(difference_gradient(true, vertical=False) - difference_gradient(pred, vertical=False)), alpha)
  # normalization over all dimensions
  return (tf.reduce_mean(true_pred_diff_vert) + tf.reduce_mean(true_pred_diff_hor)) / tf.to_float(2)


def difference_gradient(image, vertical=True):
  """
  :param image: Tensor of shape (batch_size, frame_height, frame_width, num_channels)
  :param vertical: boolean that indicates whether vertical or horizontal pixel gradient shall be computed
  :return: difference_gradient -> Tenor of shape (:, frame_height-1, frame_width, :) if vertical and (:, frame_height, frame_width-1, :) else
  """
  s = tf.shape(image)
  if vertical:
    return tf.abs(image[:, 0:s[1] - 1, :, :] - image[:, 1:s[1], :, :])
  else:
    return tf.abs(image[:, :, 0:s[2]-1,:] - image[:, :, 1:s[2], :])
```

I just had to adjust the original code line below:

```
return (tf.reduce_mean(true_pred_diff_vert) + tf.reduce_mean(true_pred_diff_hor)) / tf.to_float(2)
```

to:

```
return (tf.reduce_mean(true_pred_diff_vert) + tf.reduce_mean(true_pred_diff_hor)) / tf.cast(2, tf.float32)
```

due to the specific version of TensorFlow I'm using (based on help obtained from https://github.com/google/tangent/issues/95#issuecomment-562551139).

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78115217/2369957.

Answer (score -1):

Use the keras backend.
If backend is tensorflow, then use the K.conv3d to calculate the gradient.

Comment: I found the answer very vague, I couldn't understand what should be done.