# Gradient Difference Loss of two images in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, loss-function

How can I implement the Gradient Difference Loss of two images in TensorFlow (in sequential model), like that made using PyTorch (https://github.com/mmany/pytorch-GDL/blob/main/custom_loss_functions.py)? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in https://github.com/jonasrothfuss/DeepEpisodicMemory/blob/master/models/loss_functions.py

```
def gradient_difference_loss(true, pred, alpha=2.0):
  """
  computes gradient difference loss of two images
  :param ground truth image: Tensor of shape (batch_size, frame_height, frame_width, num_channels)
  :param predicted image: Tensor of shape (batch_size, frame_height, frame_width, num_channels)
  :param alpha parameter of the used l-norm
  """
  #tf.assert_equal(tf.shape(true), tf.shape(pred))
  # vertical
  true_pred_diff_vert = tf.pow(tf.abs(difference_gradient(true, vertical=True) - difference_gradient(pred, vertical=True)), alpha)
  # horizontal
  true_pred_diff_hor = tf.pow(tf.abs(difference_gradient(true, vertical=False) - difference_gradient(pred, vertical=False)), alpha)
  # normalization over all dimensions
  return (tf.reduce_mean(true_pred_diff_vert) + tf.reduce_mean(true_pred_diff_hor)) / tf.to_float(2)


def difference_gradient(image, vertical=True):
  """
  :param image: Tensor of shape (batch_size, frame_height, frame_width, num_channels)
  :param vertical: boolean that indicates whether vertical or horizontal pixel gradient shall be computed
  :return: difference_gradient -> Tenor of shape (:, frame_height-1, frame_width, :) if vertical and (:, frame_height, frame_width-1, :) else
  """
  s = tf.shape(image)
  if vertical:
    return tf.abs(image[:, 0:s[1] - 1, :, :] - image[:, 1:s[1], :, :])
  else:
    return tf.abs(image[:, :, 0:s[2]-1,:] - image[:, :, 1:s[2], :])
```

I just had to adjust the original code line below:

```
return (tf.reduce_mean(true_pred_diff_vert) + tf.reduce_mean(true_pred_diff_hor)) / tf.to_float(2)
```

to:

```
return (tf.reduce_mean(true_pred_diff_vert) + tf.reduce_mean(true_pred_diff_hor)) / tf.cast(2, tf.float32)
```

due to the specific version of TensorFlow I'm using (based on help obtained from https://github.com/google/tangent/issues/95#issuecomment-562551139).